# How to identify unique users while letting them login with LinkedIn?

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

So I send the user to LinkedIn, which sends them back to `redirect_url` with a code. I trade that code for an access token. How do I tell which user has logged in? I have a SQL table of users:

CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    access_token TEXT);

so I'm guessing at my handler for `redirect_url`, I grab an access token, and then see which user in my table has that access token? But the access token changes?

My question is: once the user logs in through LinkedIn and gets redirected to my url, how do I differentiate between different users on the server-side?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to call [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address)](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~%3a%28id,email-address%29) using access_token to get user's Id. This Id is unique for that user. You can save that Id in database and reference that for identifying the user.

BUT Linkedin API has a VERY BAD thing. Keep in mind, if you change the API Key ( if some day you decide to use a different API key for any reason ) then you will not get same "Id" of the user. This Id is API Key specific. So you will have no way of identifying the user is same or not. You can save email-address too, but that can be changed by user anyways.

Hope this helps.